# Blocking all requests through .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I've been reading a lot about this but can't find a definitive anwser. I'm trying to block a few sites from making ANY request to my server.  Here's what I have.  But it seems some sites can still pull data from me through jquery. I'd also like to block any sub domains of sites, ie "mysite.webs.com". Any ideas? Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?webs\.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?3dn\.ru$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?skyaccess\.se$
#RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Pull data through jQuery? How have you traced that? What kind of requests are they performing?

Comment: Another possible option is to block all sites and only allow those sites that you are alright with accessing your stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `%{SERVER_NAME}` will always be your site or one of its virtual hosts, so I don't think that is going to work.

You could try to block traffic from referring sites:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} webs\.com [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 3dn\.ru [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} skyaccess\.se
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 1):

Will

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} anotherbadsite\.com
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

do what you wish?
Source: [Blocking users/ sites by referrer](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess14.shtml)

Comment: *I'm trying to block a **few** sites*. A few, not all.

Comment: Sorry, edited, I missed the part where you said specific sites.

Comment: It was my fault anyway :) But did it solve your problem?

Comment: It's not my problem ;)

Comment: I don't know. You'd have to ask the OP. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't, though.

Comment: Ahaha, sorry, I didn't realize you weren't the OP :)